# How to write contents of json to a csv file in python?

Tags: python, json, csv

I have a list of returned values from a json file

```
2020-09-08 - 11290
2020-09-09 - 11290
2020-09-10 - 11290
2020-09-11 - 12290
```

I saved above values to a variable "data". These values are returned from a json list by using print(data)

```
print(f"{node['X']} - {node['Y']}") #print(data)
```

I want this list of returned values into a csv file with a header "X" and "Y"

```
fieldnames = ['X', 'Y']
with open('mydata.csv', 'w') as f:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames=fieldnames)
    writer.writeheader()
    writer.writerows(chain.from_iterable(data))
```

This piece of code is returning empty data with just two headers given "X" and "Y"
It would be great if i get a suggestion or a solution with some example.
Thanks for the help!

Comment: did you think about how the format will fit? What about a list, sublist on the JSON

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I convert JSON to CSV?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1871524/how-can-i-convert-json-to-csv)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it might be worth mentioning your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64926393/webscraping-data-from-an-interactive-graph-from-a-website) or at least providing more details related to the data you're trying to write.

Anyhow, this should get you what you want:

```
import csv
import requests

response = requests.get('https://www.prisjakt.nu/_internal/graphql?release=2020-11-20T07:33:45Z|db08e4bc&version=6f2bf5&main=product&variables={"id":5183925,"offset":0,"section":"statistics","statisticsTime":"1970-01-02","marketCode":"se","personalizationExcludeCategories":[],"userActions":true,"badges":true,"media":true,"campaign":true,"relatedProducts":true,"campaignDeals":true,"priceHistory":true,"recommendations":true,"campaignId":2,"personalizationClientId":"","pulseEnvironmentId":"sdrn:schibsted:environment:undefined"}').json()

with open("your_data.csv", "w") as output:
    w = csv.DictWriter(output, fieldnames={"date", "lowestPrice"})
    w.writeheader()
    for node in response["data"]["product"]["statistics"]["nodes"]:
        w.writerow(node)
```

Output from the .csv file:

```
lowestPrice,date
13195,2019-09-10
12990,2019-09-11
12990,2019-09-12
12605,2019-09-13
12605,2019-09-14
12605,2019-09-15
12970,2019-09-16
12970,2019-09-17
12970,2019-09-18
...
```

Comment: Neat and clean. 
You are really fast. I would learn these skills from you. Thanks for the help!

Comment: If you want the date first, just swap the order of `fieldnames`.

Comment: Yes, i got that

Comment: Cool! Happy coding!